# cakephp error login when I type a wrong url

Tags: cakephp, redirect

This is my problem: I have a admin area and I protect it by a login with name and password .
When I type the url I mean something like that localhost/admin/area it redirect to localhost/user/admin
The problem is if I type a wrong address like localhost/admin/545
It toke me to the admin area and an error in Controller
This is my code:

**AppController:**

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>false);
    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
    if(!isset($this->request->params['prefix']))
    {
       $this->Auth->allow();
    }
    if(isset($this->request->params['prefix']) && $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin')
    {    
      $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
}

function isAuthorized($user)
{
    if(!isset($this->request->params['prefix']))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**menu:**

```
<?php
    $pages = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'menu','admin'=>false)); ?>
    <a href="/index"><img class="title" src="/img/title.png" alt="studio"></a>
    <ul class="menu">
    <?php foreach($pages as $k => $v): $v = current($v);?>
```

**and the rest of code is:**

**function for login:**

```
function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
           $this->Session->setFlash("Votre login ou votre mot de passe ne correspond pas");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Format you code so people can see what is going on.

Comment: And specify which is the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting confused on the URLs in CakePHP. Here I will cover how they work. I will assume that you have admin routing turned on.

**localhost/admin/area**
This url is saying take me to the `admin_index` method in the `area` controller.

**localhost/admin/545**
This url is saying take me to the `admin_index` method in the `545` controller.

If the controller does not exist, you are going to get an area. If you are trying to get to a specific user_id, you may be looking for:

```
localhost/admin/user/view/545
```

This will attempt to route the user to the `admin_view` method in the `user` controller and pass the 545 user_id. If the user does not have permission to view this, they will be redirected to the login.